# How to recognize a Germanium Diode

Tags: diodes, identification

I am in a little trouble and seeking some help. I got a bunch of mixed up diodes from an old collection. I know there are few diodes which are Germanium Diodes. But they look so similar to 1N4148 and similar transparent case diodes. The problem is, the diodes are old (but working) and it's very difficult to read the numbers printed on them. How can I identify and distinguish Germanium diodes? Can I measure something with a multimeter, or create a simple circuit to identify the Germanium diodes. I am looking for identifying diodes like 1N60 and 1N34A. I would highly appreciate your help!

Comment: First google on germanium diode characteristics gives me: "For silicon diodes, the built-in potential is approximately 0.7 V (0.3 V for germanium and 0.2 V for Schottky)." (Although I don't like the term **built-in potential**. I prefer **forward voltage drop**.)

Comment: Forward voltage will be lower on germanium diodes IRC.

Comment: What do you need these for? Xtal Radio?

Comment: Typical small signal Germanium diodes have a needle contact and look like this: https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fil:Germanium_Diode_OA85.JPG

Comment: Funny way to test if you have any germanium diodes is to make an old AM radio circuit. If it is germanium the circuit would work. 

Comment: @Bix I want to use the Germanium diodes for that purpose only!! :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this schematic to test the diodes. You can easily distinguish Silicon and Germanium Diodes. Silicon diodes should read approx 0.7V and Germanium diodes should read 0.3V. A little difficult to distinguish Schottky diodes though. They should show approx 0.2V which is close to 0.3V. If you have a very stable power supply and a good meter you can distinguish this as well!

Good Luck!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Dkjn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the schematic! It worked. I am able to distinguish the diodes easily!

Comment: You can also likely tell the difference between Ge and Schottky diodes by reverse-biasing it and looking at the leakage current. With a Schottky diode, you will see a current on the order of microamps, and the 0 if it is Ge.

Answer (score 12):

Germanium diodes have a lower forward voltage drop than silicon diodes.  Rig up something that puts a little current thru them, and measure the voltage.

For example, a 5 kΩ resistor in series with a 5 V supply should do quite well.  The current will is limited to 1 mA, and the reverse voltage to 5 V.  Neither should hurt any of the diodes you have.

Silicon diodes will have around 650 mV forward drop.  Germanium will have about half that.

Note that silicon Schottky diodes have about the same voltage drop as germanium diodes.  If you think there might be some Schottky diodes in the mix, then it gets more complicated.

Comment: For Schottky reverse current is useful to. There are cheap devices on eBay called "transistor tester", based on some electronics forum design. They measure that and capacitance too, and despite being not very accurate I find that little thing a very valuable tool in parts identification

Comment: @Plasm: Yes, you'd probably need to use reverse current to distinguish between germanium and silicon Schottky diodes, especially at elevated temperatures.  I wasn't going to get into that unless the OP came back and said that there might be Schottky diodes in the mix.

Comment: Aren't germanium diodes rather leaky as well?

Comment: last time I did the sums, 5v/1k was 5mA, not 1mA

Comment: @Neil_UK: you mean last time you did the quotients ;-)

Comment: @Curd - Very drole. I'd not really noticed that 'sums' were a subset of arithmetic, in addition to being very simple (the intent) arithmetic. I prefer not to use math(s), as the spelling varies by which side of the pond.

Comment: @Neil: Oops. Fixed.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Luckily there was only couple of Schottky diodes and I could read their numbers :)

Comment: @Amanda: But how do you know the ones you couldn't read and that seemed to be germanium weren't silicon Schottky?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I knew the most reputed user on Stack ECE will definitely ask this question :)
In my case, fortunately I had a full list of part numbers of these diodes printed on a paper. I just had to match the count with the list and sort the Germanium ones. I had only two Schottky diodes, printed on the list :)

Answer (score 7):

The continuity test function on many multimeters has a "diode" setting that will tell you what the forward voltage is, from which you can infer the type of diode.

http://en-us.fluke.com/training/training-library/test-tools/digital-multimeters/how-to-test-diodes-using-a-digital-multimeter.html

Comment: Thanks for this, I was wondering what the diode symbol on my MM was for.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes now I am effectively using the Diode setting on my DMM. Thanks for the clue! :)

Answer (score 3):

Using diode test mode on a DMM is the best way. It will use some standard fixed current like 1mA to measure voltage up to maybe 3V. This is also useful for comparing LEDs.  If you dont have a DMM, get a good one.

### Opinion

There is no real need for old Ge , as Schottky performs better and diode capacitance * forward Rs= (ESR) resistance , which is relatively constant is better on Schottky and ESR=k/Pd for power rating Pd.

In fact [some](https://www.google.ca/search?q=1N60&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=zDV3WpuIJYLM8AehyKPgCQ) manufacturers are making the 1N60 with Schottky Silicon instead of the original Germanium.

Comment: If you want to produce a noise signal, some low-voltage circuits specify Germanium diodes because their breakdown voltage is very low. But today one could use a blue LED for the same purpose. Or use a voltage doubler somewhere.

Comment: The "real need" is in applications that rely on the exact characteristic curve, which is quite different for GE vs Schottky ... mostly RF or musician's gear. Anything that needs to distort/create a logarithm instead of just rectify.

Answer (score 3):

Real world germanium diodes (even recent production) almost always come in a larger glass body (diameter about equal to or even thicker than a 1N4007, slightly longer. Not unlike a small reed switch), either left clear or painted black. With clear case examples, the insides will appear mostly see-through hollow (instead of mostly filled with red/orange copper tampers, like you will see on a 1N4148 or similar), sometimes with a visible hair thin wire going towards the actual semiconductor element.

This old case style has been used for silicon parts too, but is VERY uncommon for them.

Germanium semiconductors in molded plastic cases are an ABSOLUTE exception (only one I am aware of is the AF279 HF transistor), since most germanium parts were made in processes that require the part to be kept in a clean, hermetically sealed case (which plastic molding does not reliably provide). So, anything plastic molded will be silicon.

For power diodes, the same style of metal cases have been used for both Si and Ge devices.

If the labelling is partially readable: european parts whose designation starts with "A" are always germanium, "O" is so old that is is LIKELY germanium, "B" is silicon.